# Showing that a subset is a submanifold?

Tags: manifolds

I'm new in the subject of manifolds, and I do not know very much about them: I just think about it as subsets of some n-dimensional Eculidean space, that are smooth etc. But I don't know/cannot use the rigorous definitions of manifolds at the moment. So please can somebody help me :)

Let $$ G=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3|} x^2+y^2-z^2+1=0; z>0\} $$

*Question 1*: Is $h(u,v) = (u,v, \sqrt{u^2+v^2+1}) $ a correct parameterization?

*Question 2*: How can I show that this is a 2-dimensional submanifold  of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

I've got two equivalent definitions of manifolds, namely:

**Defintion 1**
A nonempty subset M of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $k$-dimensional $C^l$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $l\ge1$, if for each $p\in M $ there is a neighborhood $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a $C^l$-map $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k} $ such that

1. rank$D_xF=n-k$, for $x\in M\cap U$
2. $M\cap U = \{x\in U|F(x)=0 \}$

**Definition 2**
A nonempty subset M of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $k$-dimensional $C^l$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $l\ge1$, if for each $p\in M $ there is a neighborhood $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a $C^l$-map $h:V \rightarrow U\cap M$ of an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^k $ onto $U\cap M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

1. $h$ is differentiable
2. $h$ is a homeomorphism
3. For each $q\in V$ the derivative $D_qh: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is one-to-one

Which one should I use? How?

Should I just show that the rank of $D_xF$ equals 1? Where $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2+1=0$?
Or should I show that my parameterization is differentiable, a homeomorphism and for each point that the derivative $D_qh$ is a bijection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the easiest way to go is to use the so called submersion property :
if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a smooth function such that $D_xf$ is surjective on an open neighborhood of $M=f^{-1}(0)$ then $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-p$.

Here $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2+1$, and you just need to check that the differential does not vanish near the set $M$ of its zeroes. This will prove that $M$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. a surface).

Your parametrization is correct.

Comment: $z>0$ is assumed in the def. of $G$.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: What do you mean by checking that the differential does not vanish near the set M of its zeroes? How can I relate this by one of my definitions?

Comment: @berci : you are right. so it is a global paramtrization.
joyeuse saint valentin : this is just your definition 1, and the remark that in this case having rank 1 is the same as not vanishing.

Comment: $df = 2xdx+2ydy-2zdz$ is the differential. Is this object nonzero near $M$?

Comment: Since we assumed $z>0$, then yes, $-2zdz \neq 0$ and therefore $df\neq 0$.